# How to get netplan to set the dns server in /etc/resolv.conf based on info coming from the dhcp server?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, dhcp, dnsmasq, netplan

I'm setting up a 4 x RPi Cluster with the following simple network topology:

[image]

All 4 RPi nodes have the latest Ubuntu Server LTS 20.04 OS. rpi1 is my primary/gateway node. I did the following on rpi1:

- Assigned a static IP Address on eth0 of 10.0.0.1 using netplan
- Disabled `systemd-resolved` and manually created `/etc/resolv.conf` with value `nameserver 127.0.0.1`
- Setup `dnsmasq` with the following `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
# Basics:
interface=eth0
listen-address=127.0.0.1

# DHCP Settings (MAC Addresses removed)
dhcp-range=10.0.0.1,10.0.0.128,12h

dhcp-host=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,rpi1,10.0.0.1
dhcp-host=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,rpi2,10.0.0.2
dhcp-host=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,rpi3,10.0.0.3
dhcp-host=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,rpi4,10.0.0.4

dhcp-option=option:router,10.0.0.1
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,10.0.0.1
dhcp-option=option:netmask,255.255.255.0

# Forward to nameservers:
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4

# Misc
bind-interfaces
domain-needed
bogus-priv
expand-hosts
```

- Added identities to the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
10.0.0.1 rpi1
10.0.0.2 rpi2
10.0.0.3 rpi3
10.0.0.4 rpi4
```

This setup seems to work succcesfuly as a DHCP server as it correctly assigns the desired IP Addresses to the eth0 devices of the remaining "minor" nodes (rpi2, rpi3, rpi4) based on their MAC address.

HOWEVER, I can't figure out how to use netplan on the minor nodes to register the nameserver being broadcast by the dnsmasq-DHCP server running on rpi1. I've tried all sorts of settings in the `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` file on a minor node, but when I run `sudo netplan apply`, it ALWAYS creates a `/etc/resolv.conf` file with the following nameserver-location info:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

If I manually edit `/etc/resolv.conf` to point to rpi1 (`nameserver 10.0.0.1`) then it works (e.g. I can then `ping rpi3` from rpi2), but I would like to understand why running `netplan apply` doesn't set this automatically based on info coming from the dnsmasq broadcast. I've tried various settings in my `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`, but nothing seems to affect the resultant `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Here's where I got to last on the `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` file on rpi2 before giving up (note: I also enable direct wifi access here for initial setup/debugging):

```
network:
    version: 2    
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
            dhcp4-overrides:
                use-dns: false
            nameservers:
                addresses: [10.0.0.1]
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            optional: true
            access-points:
                "my-wifi-signal":
                    password: "mypassword"
            dhcp4: no
            addresses: [192.168.0.52/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

It's also odd to me that when I run `systemd-resolve --status` after applying netplan with this config, it seems to indicate that it DOES now recognize the location of the desired DNS nameserver on rpi1:

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
...

Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 10.0.0.1
         DNS Servers: 10.0.0.1
```

... but, as I said, when I try to e.g. `ping rpi4` from rpi3 it doesn't work (I get the message "ping: rpi4: Temporary failure in name resolution").

In summary:

How can I make it so that running `sudo netplan apply` will consult the DHCP server for a DNS Nameserver and use that to set the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`?